# Pareto-optimal front $F$ in $m$-dimensional space can not have more than $\mathbf{H}_{m-2}(F)$ homology groups

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, convex-optimization

I need to prove that a [Pareto-optimal front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier) $F$ in $m$-dimensional space (i.e. $m > 1$) can not have more than $\mathbf{H}_{m-2}(F)$ [homology groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)).

What it simply means that in a 2-dimensional Pareto-optimal front can't have 1 and 2-dimensional holes (due to the dominance relation), but it can have a 0-dimensional persistence homology (i.e. number of connected components). A 3-dimensional Pareto-optimal front can't have 2 and 3-dimensional persistence homology (due to the dominance relation), but it can have a 1-dimensional holes (i.e. loops) and so on.

This is my proof strategy:

In a geometrically realized $k$-simplex $\sigma_k$, the $k+1$ points $\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2, \ldots ,\mathbf{u}_{k+1} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ are affinely independent. Where $\mathbf{u}_i = [f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m] \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $m > 2$. Then, the simplex determined by them is the set of points
\begin{align}
    \sigma_k=\left\{\theta_1 \mathbf{u}_1 + \theta_2 \mathbf{u}_2 + \ldots + \theta_{k+1} \mathbf{u}_{k+1} \mid \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \theta_{i}=1 \text { and } \forall\, i\,\,\theta_{i} \geq 0\right\}
\end{align}
Let's exclude an arbitrary point $\mathbf{u}_j$ from $\sigma_k$ and construct a new simplex $\sigma_{k-1}$:
\begin{align}
    \sigma_{k-1}=\left\{\theta_1 \mathbf{u}_1 + \theta_2 \mathbf{u}_2 + \ldots + \theta_{j-1} \mathbf{u}_{j-1} + \theta_{j+1} \mathbf{u}_{j+1} + \ldots + \theta_{k} \mathbf{u}_{k} \mid \sum_{i=1}^{k} \theta_{i}=1 \text { and } \forall\, i\,\,\theta_{i} \geq 0\right\}
\end{align}

Now what I want to show that there are always a subset of points in $\sigma_{k-1}$ that [Pareto-dominate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) $\mathbf{u}_j$. If I can do that then I can say in a Pareto-optimal front, the highest dimensional simplex that exists is $\sigma_{k-1}$.

Hopefully from there the rest of the proof about $\mathbf{H}_{m-2}(F)$ should be easy.

But I can't sort this out. Also not sure if I am even going on a right direction.

**Alternative strategy:** use the idea from Section 4.7.3 from Boyd's [Convex Optimization](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) book. The book talks about the notion of *boundary* $\mathrm{bd}$ of a feasible objective space $\mathcal{O}$ . But $\mathrm{bd}\mathcal{O}$ is not clearly defined in terms of simplicial complexes.

Comment: What's $H_{m-2}$?

Comment: For that matter, how are you quantifying homology groups?

Comment: Oh maybe you mean the homology vanishes for degrees above $m-2$. Is that the question?

Comment: @GregFriedman I have modified the description, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Spaces have infinitely many  homology  groups.  Perhaps you could clarify, what would it mean to you for a space to have only one homology group?  Without additional quantifiers I don't see a way to make sense of that expression.